# How do i show widget when look at object unreal?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I want to show the widget when player look at tht object, when player look other side widget has to disapper, how do i achieve that in unrea ngine

Answer (score 1):

You would use a line trace similar to [this article](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Physics/Tracing/HowTo/SingleLineTraceByObject/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function "Find Look at Rotation" so then you can compare the player actual rotation with that rotation, so it will be less expensive than a line trace for example